# Apache lucene 4.3.1 - Index reader is not reach to the last indexed document

Tags: lucene

In My App I have documents represents my data for each category, my application perform an automatic index to new and the modified documents.

if i performed index for all documents in one category, its work fine and retrieve a correct results, but the problem is, if i modified or create new document its will not retrieve it, if its matched my search query.

usually keeps return all docs except the last modified one.

any help please ?

I have this IndexWriter config :

```
private IndexWriter getIndexWriter() throws IOException {

     Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(new File(filepath));
     IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_43, IndexFactory.ANALYZER);
     config.setRAMBufferSizeMB(350);

     TieredMergePolicy tmp = new TieredMergePolicy();
     tmp.setUseCompoundFile(false);
     config.setMergePolicy(tmp);

     ConcurrentMergeScheduler scheduler = (ConcurrentMergeScheduler) config.getMergeScheduler();
     scheduler.setMaxThreadCount(2);
     scheduler.setMaxMergeCount(20);

     IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
     writer.forceMerge(1);

     return writer;
```

My Collector :

```
public void collect(int docNum) throws IOException {
    try {
        if ((getCount() == getMaxSearchLimit() + 1) && getMaxSearchResults() != null) {
            setCounterExceededLimit(true);
            return;
        }

        addDocKey();// method to add and render the matching docs by customize way
    } catch(IOException exp) {
        if (!getErrors().toArrayList(getApplication().getLocale()).contains(exp.getMessage())) {
            getErrors().addError(exp.getMessage());
        }
    } catch (BusinessException bEx) {
        if (!getErrors().containsError(bEx.getErrorNumber())) {
            getErrors().addError(bEx);
        }
    } catch (CounterExceededLimitException counterEx) {
        return;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean acceptsDocsOutOfOrder() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public void setNextReader(AtomicReaderContext context) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void setScorer(Scorer scorer) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

acually i have this busniess logic to save my doc, then i asked if the doc saved successfully to add it to the index process.

```
public boolean saveDocument(CategoryDocument doc) {
boolean saved = false;

// code to save my doc 

if(saved) {
    //add this document to the index process
    IndexManager.getInstance().addToIndex(this);
}
```

}

then my index manager create a new thread to handle indexing this doc.
here is my process to index my data document :

```
private void processDocument(IndexDocument indexDoc, DocKey docKey, boolean addToIndex) throws SearchException, BusinessException {
    CategorySetting catSetting = docKey.getCategorySetting();
    Integer catID = catSetting.getID();
    IndexManager manager = IndexManager.getInstance();
    IndexWriter writer = null;

    try {

        //Delete the lock file in case previous index operation failed to delete it
        File lockFile = new File(filepath, IndexWriter.WRITE_LOCK_NAME);
        if (lockFile != null && lockFile.exists()) {
            lockFile.delete();
        }

        if(!manager.isGlobalIndexingProcess(catID)) {
            writer = getIndexWriter();
        } else {
            writer = manager.getGlobalIndexWriter(catID);
        }
        writer.forceMerge(1);

        removeDocument(docKey, writer);

        if (addToIndex) {
            writer.addDocument(indexDoc.getLuceneIndexDoc());
        }
    } catch(IOException exp) {
        throw new SearchException(exp.getMessage(), true);
    } finally {

        if(!manager.isGlobalIndexingProcess(catID)) {
            if (writer != null) {
                try {
                    writer.close(true); 
                } catch(IOException ex) {
                    throw new SearchException(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain clearly what actually you are expecting with the program and where it is having false functioning.

Comment: please see my edited question, i faced this problem couple days ago, and still occur, i tried many thing but without any progress. if you can help me I'd be grateful to you. thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok you just have to perform indexing process after every change whether it is adding or editing a document. See lucene creates lucene document out of your documents which it puts in index, and these are hit against search query. So you have you allow your newly added document to get indexed otherwise they will not appear in search result.

Comment: yea sure i do, my documents will be indexed successfully after adding or editing them, in addition to the description above i noticed that the last new or the edited document become the last hit, but my collector is not reach it, it collect the first document again instead of it. example, if i have a
     1 2 3 docs and added new one 4, and search for all of them it will retrieve
     1231 insted of
     1234.

Comment: You sure the newly added documents are indexed.

Comment: yea i am pretty sure. i think maybe you have to see lucene files, but i don't know to in here, i think its will give you a clear image that whats happening.

Comment: just try this add or edit any document and then immediately call indexing process.

Comment: after getting a positive hit of a document against a query you are calling collect function and document number you are calling is correct.

Comment: sorry i didn't understand what do mean in the last comment.

Comment: we need to know the flow of program , just function definition is not enough

Comment: Ok first do indexing process then for any keyword check files are actually indexed or not. Dont pass the result to collector just check raw results are obtained or not.

Comment: yea, my files have been changed.

Answer (score 0):

Use lucene search and search for the word or phrase that you edited in the document and let us know whether you get the correct hits or not. If you didn't get any hits then probably you are not indexing edited or newly added documents.

Comment: no i didn't get it, i get the first indexed document. when i traced my collector, its show that its not reach the last lucene document, its collect the 0 (first hit) document again instead of the last hit (last added or edited document). also i have added more description above about my work flow, thanks.

Comment: I think your index didn't update. Update your IndexWriter Config, add : `config.setMergePolicy(new UpgradeIndexMergePolicy(config.getMergePolicy()));` above `config.setRAMBufferSizeMB(350);`.

Comment: its return the first document only, in any query i use. and if there any suggest solution ill be grateful, thanks.

Comment: Pardon me, I didn't really understand what you mean to say by "no i didn't get it, I get the first indexed document". Did you really tried the method I suggested first. OR you get the first indexed document after performing a lucene search.Could you also find the total document indexed in your index. Repeat same after adding another document and editing one document.

Comment: ok am sorry, ok i meant after adding your line of code, when i perform any search query it keeps return the first indexed document, example if i have 1234 docs and performed a search query to get them all, it'll return 1111 instead of 1234. and about your questions, yea i get the correct total of my indexed docs, and its not repeating the same result, as i said above, its repeating the first doc, example if i have 1234 doc, then performed a search query to get them all, its will return 1231, means the last edited or added document will not show up.

Comment: thanks a lot, i have solved this issue, the problem was in my Collector, what i should have do is to re-base the docID by recording the docBase from the most recent setNextReader call.
    public void setNextReader(AtomicReaderContext context) {
     this.docBase = context.docBase;
   }

then in my collect method : docNum += docBase;